# Get Hour of a specific TimeZone in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, format, timezone

I have to display in a Flutter app, the time (HH:MM) of a flight in the local time of the country where the flight is taking off or landing. And NOT according to the timezone of the mobile device

So, how can I get the specific time format (HH:MM) of a Timezone, knowing that I got 2 different TZ format (according to source). Either such as `Europe/London` or could be `+04:00`

I have seen possibly 2 libraries `timezone`  or `time_machine`  but don't know if it is good fit

Many thanks

Comment: Try this intl class: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the `DateTime` class of Dart only supports UTC and the local timezone. I suggest using the following third party package:

https://pub.dev/packages/timezone

It supports time zones:

```dart
import 'package:timezone/standalone.dart' as tz;

Future<void> setup() async {
  await tz.initializeTimeZone();
  var detroit = tz.getLocation('America/Detroit');
  var now = tz.TZDateTime.now(detroit);
}
```

Comment: I have tried and it worked, thanks a lot

Comment: Do you know if there is a way of using ``UTC+01:00`` instead of ``Europe/London`` I don't see anything in the doc?

Comment: I haven't tried it , but you could probably declare your own `TimeZone` instances. There is already a constant for `UTC`. So you could try to introduce your own "UTC+01:00" with the corresponding offset, for example: https://pub.dev/documentation/timezone/latest/timezone.standalone/TimeZone/UTC-constant.html

And feel free to accept the answer, if it solves your problem :D